# Microsoft Azure Webapp deployment error in Production slot

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-webapps, kudu, azure-deployment-slots

Since the end of August since July we have had problems deploying on WebApps via Azure DevOps or kudu.

the errors that emerge is not really explicit:

```
2022-09-06T16:11:48.4467209Z Using the following command to generate deployment script: 'azure site deploymentscript -y --no-dot-deployment -r "C:\local\Temp\zipdeploy\extracted" -o "C:\home\site\deployments\tools" --basic --sitePath "C:\local\Temp\zipdeploy\extracted"'.
2022-09-06T16:11:48.4468177Z C:\PROGRA~2\SITEEX~1\NODEAP~1\298144~1.4\nodejs\node_modules\open\index.js:38
2022-09-06T16:11:48.4468606Z        } catch {}
2022-09-06T16:11:48.4468848Z                ^
2022-09-06T16:11:48.4468969Z 
2022-09-06T16:11:48.4469262Z SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
2022-09-06T16:11:48.4469684Z     at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
2022-09-06T16:11:48.4470105Z     at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
2022-09-06T16:11:48.4470545Z     at Module._compile (module.js:616:28)
2022-09-06T16:11:48.4471047Z     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
2022-09-06T16:11:48.4471513Z     at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
2022-09-06T16:11:48.4471942Z     at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
2022-09-06T16:11:48.4472389Z     at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
2022-09-06T16:11:48.4472810Z     at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
2022-09-06T16:11:48.4473206Z     at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
2022-09-06T16:11:48.4473789Z     at Object.<anonymous> (C:\PROGRA~2\SITEEX~1\NODEAP~1\298144~1.4\nodejs\node_modules\@azure\identity\dist\index.js:22:12)
2022-09-06T16:11:48.4476491Z C:\PROGRA~2\SITEEX~1\NODEAP~1\298144~1.4\nodejs\node_modules\open\index.js:38\r\n      } catch {}\r\n              ^\r\n\r\nSyntaxError: Unexpected token {\r\n    at createScript (vm.js:80:10)\r\n    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)\r\n    at Module._compile (module.js:616:28)\r\n    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)\r\n    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)\r\n    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)\r\n    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)\r\n    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)\r\n    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)\r\n    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\PROGRA~2\SITEEX~1\NODEAP~1\298144~1.4\nodejs\node_modules\@azure\identity\dist\index.js:22:12)\r\nC:\Program Files (x86)\SiteExtensions\Kudu\97.40810.5869\bin\Scripts\starter.cmd "C:\Program Files (x86)\SiteExtensions\Kudu\97.40810.5869\bin\node_modules\.bin\kuduscript.cmd" -y --no-dot-deployment -r "C:\local\Temp\zipdeploy\extracted" -o "C:\home\site\deployments\tools" --basic --sitePath "C:\local\Temp\zipdeploy\extracted"
2022-09-06T16:11:48.4479031Z Deployment Failed.
2022-09-06T16:11:48.4505538Z ##[error]Failed to deploy web package to App Service.
2022-09-06T16:11:48.4513364Z ##[error]Error: Package deployment using ZIP Deploy failed. Refer logs for more details.
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem comes from the version of nodejs configured on the webapp via the appsetting: WEBISTE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION

Upgrade from 8.11.1 to 16.9.1 resolve the problem